# aJax Javascript Multiple Forms on Page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So I'm using this piece of javscript/ajax to create a form that submits to another page on my site without reloading the page. My question is how can I program this same code to work with multiple forms on the same page? If I have two forms that I want to submit to two separate locations how do I specify which form triggers which piece of javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'csverify.php',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        console.log("Signup was successful");
      },//here
      error: function() {
        console.log("Signup was unsuccessful");
      }
    });});//here
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    submit();
});
</script>
```

Not sure if it matters but I would like to use either name="" or ID="" to designate each form with a name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method passing form's ID.Then get the form attribute `action` on different by form's ID.

**Html part**

```
<form id="form1" action="form1.php">
    ...
</form>


<form id="form2" action="form2.php">
    ...
</form>
```

**JS part**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit(formID) {
        var $form = $('#'+formID);
        $form.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: $form.attr('action'),
              data: $form.serialize(),
              success: function() {
                console.log("Signup was successful");
              },//here
              error: function() {
                console.log("Signup was unsuccessful");
              }
            });
        });//here
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        submit('form1');
        submit('form2');
    });
</script>
```